# 1 ViewModel for 2 Views (same instance) for class library with wpf views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Please bear with me as I am still new to all of this. I am currently trying to bind my two views to the same instance of my ViewModel (in xaml not code-behind). **My code is for a plugin (output is a class library .dll file) in a software so its not setup as a C# WPF application (I dont have an App.xaml)**. I have looked into using MVVM light, viewmodellocator and all the other solutions found online but they all depend on having an App.xaml which I am not sure how to implement in my case.

As per the documentation of the software I am developing the plugin for; the entry point is a specific class (call it EntryPoint.cs for now). The Main method is used for entry. In my Main method I create my MainView.

**EntryPoint.cs:**

```
public class EntryPoint
{
    private MainView _MyForm;

    public void Main(...)
    {
            ....
            _MyForm = new MainView();
            _MyForm.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

In my mainview constructor I initiate my MainWindowViewModel.

**Mainview.cs:**

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }


}
```

SecondView is opened by a button on my MainView as follows; heres the code snippet from my MainWindowViewModel that has the command for opening my SecondView:

```
 public void OpenSecondView()
    {
        ....

        SecondView newView = new SecondView (this);
        SecondView.Show();
    }
```

I previously set the datacontext in my code-behind by having the viewmodel passed as a parameter in my constructor for my SecondView:

```
public partial class SecondView: Window
{
public SecondView(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this in my xaml? I want to bind to the same INSTANCE of my viewModel. Any guidance?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two questions here, correct? 1) How do I bind to the same instance of my viewModel in MainView and SecondView? 2) How do I achieve this in xaml, not code-behind?  The answer to the former is much easier than the latter, which would require you to show what you have actually implemented in XAML.  When you state "I am currently trying to bind my two views to the same instance of my ViewModel (in xaml not code-behind)"...show this code.  I'd be glad to help further if you can provide more clarification.

Comment: I dont have it implemented yet. I currently do the binding in code behind as seen above. I have not been able to bind it in xaml. Please let me know if I understood you correctly? Edit: when I say bind I mean set the datacontext. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you at least show where you instantiate MainViewModel, and where you instantiate SecondView? I'll post an answer to follow your implementation around those. Edit: And don't get caught up on "xaml only vs code-behind", it's not that important if functionality is what you want. It can be addressed later with refactoring.

Comment: Please take a look at updated post. Let me know if that answers you! @TamBui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**MainView.cs**

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        vm.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    public void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof("OpenSecondViewCommand")
        {
            SecondView newView = new SecondView() { DataContext = this.DataContext };
            SecondView.Show();
        }
    }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
// Get rid of your OpenSecondView() method that is tied to your Command. It is too tightly-
// coupled with the View. Instead, just use your Command public property and trigger the 
// PropertyChanged event, then let the View layer deal with what happens when you trigger 
// this Command. I don't know the name of your Command public property so I'm just going
// to assume it's called OpenSecondViewCommand. Something like this would suffice:

private RelayCommand openSecondViewCommand;
public RelayCommand OpenSecondViewCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.openSecondViewCommand == null)
            this.openSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyEventArgs(nameof(OpenSecondViewCommand)));
        return this.openSecondViewCommand;
    }
}
```

**SecondView.cs**

```
// Remove the MainWindowViewModel parameter from your c'tor.  
// Change it back to the way it was originally.

public partial class SecondView: Window
{
    public SecondView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Detailed Explanation**

One of the main aspects of the MVVM design pattern is that you define "separation of concerns" by separating and decoupling your Model from your ViewModel, and your ViewModel from your View.  This design pattern defines it this way so that you can potentially replace your entire UI with a new one, without having to touch your ViewModel code.  In your case, you have embedded your `SecondView` into your `MainWindowViewModel`.  This violates the MVVM design pattern.

Binding two Views to the same ViewModel is as simple as ensuring that the two Views have the same `DataContext`.  You can see that I've taken care of this in the `MainView.cs` by setting the `SecondView` `DataContext` property to the `MainView` `DataContext`.

```
SecondView newView = new SecondView() { DataContext = this.DataContext };
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Tam Bui. I know I had an issue with the logic behind my opening of the new window. However my main question still remains un answered; how do I set my data context to the same instance of my viewmodel in xaml not code behind. I know code behind currently works for me but Id like to learn to do it in xaml too!

Comment: @melsawy, if you want to share the `MainWindowViewModel` across two views, normally you would define it as a `StaticResource` in your `App.xaml`, but you stated you don't have one. I don't understand the workings of your dll, or how it launches your app.  But I would start by finding out how to define a shared resource programmatically for your `MainWindowViewModel` from where ever you launched your `MainWindow`.  Then, it's as simple as specifying that same `StaticResource` from both your `MainWindow` and your `SecondView`'s xaml code as their `DataContext`. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Hi Tam, can you explain this line `this.openSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyEventArgs(nameof(OpenSecondViewCommand)));` My Relaycommand constructor takes two inputs `Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute` so I dont think this code works for me. I cant get it to work atleast.

Comment: I got it to work with a few changes however my second window opens immediately.. not when I press the button. Is it possible if you produce a small working example?

Comment: The line `this.openSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyEventArgs(nameof(OpenSecondViewCommand)));` has something wrong with it. I modified it to `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OpenSecondViewCommand"));`. I have issues with the RelayCommand needing a function to point to in the Execute and a parameter.

Comment: @melsawy, I'd be happy to provide for you a small working example, if you can provide me with a small compilable example that produces your latest issue.  As I stated before, I don't know how your dll works, or how you're able to launch your MainWindow without an App.xaml.  Let me help you, by you helping me first, to get closer to your real implementation :)

Comment: I am relatively new to this so I am not sure how to replicate my example without having the actual software I am developing the plugin for. I will create a blank WPF app, how do I upload the example? Are links allowed here?

Comment: No, SO doesn't have an upload data service.  I usually just share code by zipping it up, and sharing from my throwaway google drive account.  You can create a gmail account pretty easily, and it'll give you like 15 GB of space.

Comment: Hi @Tam Bui, here you go, its in Visual Studio version 2019. I have uploaded it on a we-transfer link that will expire in 2 weeks. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4f5f5327da806f95639bf33fb9ee88cc20210527151933/6539e4eed9eb317d1cdc798a1cb4f7fd20210527152007/2a7b15

Comment: See my edits and comments that I injected into zipped project here, to explain how I got your code working: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xv_kV8-O6Dl7Hg0EmzL_6vxc0xFIbA3j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks alot Tam. I will check them tonight. I will mark your solution as "solution" even though it didnt give me the end goal but I appreciate the effort and help you provided me. (specifically quick responses)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could be of some help.